# Invalid hook call in react. I am using class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, react-redux, react-hooks

I am using `withTranslation()` in my react class component at the last line when I am exporting my application.
But it is giving below error.

[image]

Please check the last line.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Input, Form, Row, Container, Card } from 'reactstrap';
import '../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import baseUrl from '../../../base.js';
import ConfirmDlg from '../../Utils/Common/ConfirmDlg';
import { css } from 'react-emotion';
import { PropagateLoader } from 'react-spinners';
import i18next from 'i18next';
import i18n from '../../../i18n';
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
var request = require('superagent');

const override = css`
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-color: red;
`;

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
      errorMessage: '',
      isConfirmDlgOpen: false,
      isLoading: false,
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { errorMessage, isConfirmDlgOpen, isLoading } = this.state;
    const { t } = this.props;
    return <div className="wrapper">{t('Accueil')}</div>;
  }
}

export default withTranslation()(MyComponent);
```

is there any other way to handle the same. its legacy application in which I am using translation

My `package.json` file.

```
{
  "name": "myapplication",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive",
    "start": "dotenv -e .env -- webpack-dev-server --hot --define process.env.dev --inline --port 80 --host localhost",
    "build": "webpack -p --config webpack.config.js --env.prod"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bowser": "^2.1.0",
    "classnames": "^2.1.3",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "create-react-class": "^15.7.0",
    "css-hot-loader": "^1.3.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "draft-js": "^0.10.5",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "fbemitter": "^2.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "findup-sync": "^0.1.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "html-react-parser": "^0.4.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-alpha.10",
    "i18next": "^21.6.3",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.2",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.3.5",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "randomstring": "^1.1.5",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.0",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.6.0",
    "react-anything-sortable": "^1.7.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
    "react-bootstrap-date-picker-thecodingmachine": "^5.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap-native-slider": "^2.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap-slider": "^2.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap-table": "^4.1.5",
    "react-color": "^2.13.8",
    "react-datepicker": "1.6.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^4.2.3",
    "react-i18next": "^11.15.1",
    "react-modal": "^3.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scrollable-anchor": "^0.6.1",
    "react-select": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "react-signature-pad": "^0.0.6",
    "react-spinners": "^0.4.5",
    "react-star-rating": "^1.4.2",
    "react-stepzilla": "^4.6.3",
    "react-textarea-autosize": "^5.1.0",
    "react-toastify": "^3.1.0",
    "react-toggle": "^4.0.2",
    "react-transition-group": "^1.2.1",
    "reactjs-localstorage": "0.0.5",
    "reactstrap": "^4.8.0",
    "reflux": "^6.4.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "superagent": "^3.8.1",
    "transform-class-properties": "^1.0.0-beta",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2",
    "xss": "^0.3.4"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "6.26.0",
    "canvas": "1.6.7",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "dotenv-cli": "2.0.1",
    "draftjs-to-html": "^0.8.3",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "jsdom": "11.2.0",
    "mocha": "^3.3.0",
    "mocha-jsdom": "^1.1.0",
    "node-libs-browser": "^2.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "1.10.12",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.2.7",
    "react-tools": "0.13.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "source-map": "^0.6.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Given that there's nothing in your source that _directly_ causes this issue, it must indeed be in `withTranslation`. Hard to say what actually causes it without looking at the source. Your stack trace isn't helping either because it only refers to your bundle, not actual lines in your source.

Comment: Thank you @Evert . I am using legacy application. will package.json help?

Comment: You mention this being a legacy application, and I see you've a good mixture of ***really*** new npm packages with some ***really*** old packages. Did you just upgrade a bunch of them and run into this issue? Does rolling back/reverting to what you started with resolve the issue? If so, try updating a single package at-a-time and resolving specific issues you find along the way.

Answer (score 2):

You should use it like this:

```
export default withTranslation(MyComponent);
```

Answer (score 1):

run with this code and got no error

```
import React from "react";
import { withTranslation } from "react-i18next";

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: "",
      errorMessage: "",
      isConfirmDlgOpen: false,
      isLoading: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { t } = this.props;
    console.log(t);
    return <div className="wrapper">{t("xx")}</div>;
  }
}

export default withTranslation()(MyComponent);
```

might be other mistake?